# Eclipse forgets Java library in project build path

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

A co-worker gave me a second package for an Android app I'm working on and there are a couple of "java.awt" and "javax.swing" imports in the classes, which were all marked with red "x".

Eclipse (Mars.2, 4.5.2) already knows what Java versions are installed (Window - Preferences - Java - Installed JREs,  "jdk1.8.0_161" has a checkmark next to it) and I just checked if the JAVA_HOME environment variable is still there (which it is). To fix the problem, I still had to add a JRE system library (1.8.0 v161) to the project's build path.

The actual problem is: Every time I restart Eclipse, the red "x" are back and I have to add Java again.

How can I keep Eclipse from forgetting the library?

Edit: The classpath for my project says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: There might be access restrictions to these packages configured in your project's Java Build Path. What does your `.classpath` file contain? By the way, Mars.2 is outdated. Please [upgrade to Oxygen.2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F).

Comment: @howgler I updated my initial post. I'm fully aware that it's outdated, it's the version that works with the plugins I have to use (e.g. custom version of ADT).

Comment: Classes neither of `java.awt` nor of `javax.swing` can be used in an Android app. This is not an Eclipse or an IDE issue, but a restriction of Android (which uses its own UI toolkit). See the list of supported JRE packages here: https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

Comment: I'm not trying to run the code that has the JButtons,... but the alogorithm behind it and that's working just fine (already tested it). The only thing that gets imported in the actual code I'm using from the package is "java.util.ArrayList". So, the problem/my question isn't why the imports originally got marked as "x" but why Eclipse gets rid of the extra Java library every time I restart it and how I can make it keep it.

Comment: Is the following what you are looking for: in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_ click _Add Library..._ and choose a _JRE System Library_?

Comment: That's exactly what I did (check the first post please) and that's also what I have to do every time I restart Eclipse because it somehow gets rid of the Java library I added.

Comment: A normal JRE and Android are contradictory. Has the Android node a subnode _Access rules_? If not, try to add the JRE/JDK's `lib/rt.jar` via _Add External JARs..._ to your Java Build Path.

Comment: Ah, the "rt.jar" file it does remember after restarting Eclipse. Thanks! Haven't done a restart of the whole PC yet but I'll keep you updated if it still works afterwards, so you can create an answer post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `java.awt` nor `javax.swing` are part of the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) (because Android uses its own UI toolkit). You can add a JRE/JDK's **`lib/rt.jar` via *Add External JARs...*** to your Java Build Path, but that's a dirty trick.